# PySpark: Slave node cannot access hdfs. Kerberos

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs, kerberos

I have a HDFS cluster. Yarn is configured also. I can access HDFS from commandline etc... On the Resource Manager I have started a pyspark Master Node, and on one of the DataNodes I have started a pyspark Slave (pointing to the master node). Kerberos is authenticating for the HDFS cluster.

I have generated a personal keytab file.

When I submit a Job using
 ../bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --keytab ../bin/MyUsername.keytab --principal MyUsername@DOMAIN../../word_count_spark.py

It seems the Slave node cannot authenticate using Kerberos to retrieve a file from the Hadoop cluster (HDFS). I have previously read that the Master node passes the slave node Kerberos credentials for it to use However... This is the error I get,

Any leads would be greatly appreciated as would any insight !

> 2018-07-18 12:51:20 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 0.0 in stage
>   0.0 (TID 0, 130.195.4.131, executor 0): java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot
>   authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]; Host Details : local host is:
>   "SLAVE-HOSTNAME/130.19X.X.13X"; destination host is:
>   "MASTER-HOSTNAME":9000; 
>           at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:776)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:255)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callGetBlockLocations(DFSClient.java:1226)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1213)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1201)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.fetchLocatedBlocksAndGetLastBlockLength(DFSInputStream.java:306)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.openInfo(DFSInputStream.java:272)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.(DFSInputStream.java:264)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.open(DFSClient.java:1526)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:304)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:299)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSystem.java:312)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:769)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.(LineRecordReader.java:109)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.liftedTree1$1(HadoopRDD.scala:257)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.(HadoopRDD.scala:256)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:214)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:94)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
>           at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:64)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
>           at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:99)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.io.IOException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot
>   authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$1.run(Client.java:687)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)

Comment: I don't understand your mix of "standalone" cluster (Spark master + worker services) and "yarn-client" execution mode (where the driver allocates its executors directly in YARN).

Comment: Hi Samson, thanks for your response! Yes you are quite right i was mixing methodologies here -Yarn and standalone. I will change only to Yarn and ignore the stand alone master and slaves, however I would like to know how to use the master and slave with Hadoop cluster without spark. Any thoughts are warmly welcomed, and thank you for correcting me!